# Django test(django.test.client) put call, with many headers don't work

Tags: python, django

> Django (2.0)
>
> Python 3.5.2

Without `REMOTE_ADDR` it works very well:

```
client = Client()

response = client.put('/api/v1/person/address/',{},
    HTTP_API_KEY=self.model_login_director.token)
```

With `REMOTE_ADDR` in a `put()` call doesn't work (but works for `GET` and `POST` requests).

```
client = Client()

response = client.put('/api/v1/person/address/',{},
    REMOTE_ADDR='127.0.0.8',
    HTTP_API_KEY=self.model_login_director.token)
```

Message error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/wborba/project/willcode/sofia/api/test/testsControllerPersonAddress.py", line 577, in test_person_address_update_address_id_missing
        HTTP_API_KEY=self.model_login_director.token)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 548, in put
        response = super().put(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, secure=secure, **extra)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 366, in put
        secure=secure, **extra)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 404, in generic
        return self.request(**r)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/test/client.py", line 485, in request
        raise exc_value
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 89, in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
        return func(*args, **kwds)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 62, in _wrapper
        return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
        return func(*args, **kwds)
      File "/home/wborba/project/willcode/sofia/api/Business/Auth.py", line 145, in wrap
        return function(request, model_login, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 58, in bound_func
        return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
    TypeError: put() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass header information when instantiating the `Client()`

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/):

> `class Client(enforce_csrf_checks=False, **defaults)`
>
> It requires no
>   arguments at time of construction. However, you can use keywords
>   arguments to specify some default headers. For example, this will send
>   a User-Agent HTTP header in each request:
>
> `c = Client(HTTP_USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0')`

As such, you should pass the `REMOTE_ADDR` header when creating the `Client`:

```
client = Client(REMOTE_ADDR='127.0.0.8')

response = client.put('/api/v1/person/address/',{},
    HTTP_API_KEY=self.model_login_director.token)
```

Comment: this way has also been tested, I have sought all knowledge of the documentation.
I have not found in google an example of PUT with more than one HEADER.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

it was just my lack of attention.
In the method that meets the PUT request, missing there were some mandatory parameters, for example:

```
def put(self,request,model_login,*args,**kwargs):
```

i have worked with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/